# Trouble categorizing images stored in FS Collection on a meteor app

Tags: image, meteor, collections

Right now, my Meteor app is using FS Collections to store images, which only seems to only take in an image file and then store it. I was wondering if there's a way to also have it take in some descriptor, like "nature" or "portraits" so then on the client side I can sort the photos by these descriptors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you mean gridFS collections. It only takes in an image because that is all what you give.

Look for the line where you update your gridFS collection. It should look like this:

```
myImageCollection.insert(image);
```

or

```
myImageCollection.insert(image, function (err, fileObj) {
    //callback
      });
```

You can just modify this to add more data:

```
myImageCollection.insert({image_data:image, type:"photo", tags:["nature", "lolcat"]});
```

have a look at the doc for more info: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert